# Show only top level categories assigned to an entry

Tags: craft3, categories, category

Having a bit of a brainfart here...
If hotspotCategory is my entry's categoryfield and that category group has nested categories, how do I return only the top level categories?

```
{% set entryCats = entry.hotspotCategory %}
{% if entryCats | length %}
    <span class="filter_cat">
       {% for cat in entryCats %}
          {{ cat.title }} {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
     </span>
 {% endif %}
```

this works but if I do something like

```
{% set entryCats = entry.hotspotCategory.level(1).all() %}
```

I get an

```
Impossible to invoke a method ("level") on an array.
```

error.

What am I missing here?

**To clarify**: my entry has the following categories attached (slow & fast food are subcategories):

```
- food & dining
--- slow food
--- fast food
```

Now, on the entry page I only want to display the top level category, not the subcategories.

Answer (score 1):

You might want the siblings of the selected Category via `siblingOf` - I think you'll need to do this with two steps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the first level and then you have to loop through them.

```
{% set query = craft.categories().group('YOUR_CATEGORY').level(1) %}

{# Execute the query and get the results #}
{% set entries = query.all() %}

{% for entry in entries %}
   {{ entry.title }}
{% endif %}
```

This will output only the first level of the category tree.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my issue was that I was **lazy-loading hotspotCategory** which returns an array, making .level(1) impossible. Once removed from the lazyloading everything worked as expected.